# three.js lights from blender

Tags: three.js, blender

I am trying to export a scene from Blender with lights and materials. However, the lights don't translate the same as in Blender. The image below demonstrate how it looks in Blender vs Three.js. Additional information it has a material type of "MeshPhongMaterial".

Preview
[image: Preview]

Export Settings
[image: Export Settings]

This is how I'm loading it:

```
    let loader;
    if(info.isScene) { 
      loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
      loader.load(this.path + info.path, (obj) => {
        this.scene.add(obj);
      });
    }else {
      loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
      loader.load(this.path + info.path, (geometry, materials) => {
        this.b2mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
        this.b2mesh.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
        this.meshCurrentRotation = this.b2mesh.rotation;
        this.scene.add(this.b2mesh);
        this.onReady(info);
      });
    }
```

If anyone can please point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Try checking `heirarchy` as well. the blender exporter is very broken and difficult to work with

Comment: Do you have any recommendation?